# Chrome apps linked with 3dr Hextronik Antenna

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to make a chrome app that'll read data from serial port and prompt it on the app.
So far, it does work with direct usb wires (reading as a com) but when I add a USB antenna [link](https://store.3drobotics.com/products/3dr-radio) it prompts me with a read error.

Has anyone tried this before?

edit:

[Involt](http://arduinomania.com/posts/how-to-communicate-with-arduino-using-html-chrome/) , This is the program that I used as a base for my project. It works ok with cables... but it seems I'm the first to push its limits to telemetry :P

Comment: What is the actual error that you are seeing? What code are you using to read? It may be that other people can help, but haven't used that exact product.

Comment: system_error is what I'm getting. Has to be something related to the antenna for the same code works perfectly when used with the same device using USB wire. Also, I'm using the Involt Library as a base!

Comment: Please edit your question and remove "Has anyone tried this before?" from it, because that's not what you're really asking. Instead, include sample code that produces a specific troublesome behavior. Then ask why the troublesome behavior happens.